# Would a singleton Stream.empty make sense?

Tags: java, performance, java-stream

Doing some profiling of my current application the top allocation is excessive calls to `Stream.empty()` which in turn allocates a `new ReferencePipeline.Head<>` leading to lots of bogus objects.

This got me thinking, how come `Stream.empty()` doesn't simply return a special reusable singleton Stream rather than allocating new ones every time?
Would that be a good idea, and if so are there any libs/examples that already do that?

Comment: If it were a very good idea, it probably would be implemented. There's `Collections.emptyXXX()` and others in the JDK, so it's definitely in the JDK developers' toolbox. It's possible that lack of immutability or so prevents that approach from being used with streams. However I question (snootily) whether this is an actual issue. What does your application do if `Stream.empty()` is a memory hotspot?

Comment: Well, Collections.empty is exactly what got me thinking.

Comment: Note that `flatMap` allows returning `null` to represent an empty stream. This can prevent excessive creation of empty stream instances. Outside `flatMap`, this is rarely an issue.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike empty collections, streams **are mutable**, even an empty stream.

For instance, `Stream` has `close()` method which changes its state. The [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) requires that

> Operating on a stream after it has been closed will throw
>   IllegalStateException.

It also says that

> A stream should be operated on (invoking an intermediate or terminal
>   stream operation) only once. This rules out, for example, "forked"
>   streams, where the same source feeds two or more pipelines or
>   multiple traversals of the same stream. A stream implementation may
>   throw IllegalStateException if it detects that the stream is being
>   reused.

This means that caching an instance of a stream does not make sense, as the stream cannot be reused anyway.

Comment: Since detecting reuse is not mandatory, an implementation could use a cached empty stream not throwing on reuse as an implementation detail. But the presence of `onClose`+`close` prevents this.

Answer (score 2):

The Java 8 version of `Stream.empty()` is as follows.

```
public static<T> Stream<T> empty() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.<T>emptySpliterator(), false);
}
```

And in `StreamSupport`

```
public static <T> Spliterator<T> emptySpliterator() {
    return (Spliterator<T>) EMPTY_SPLITERATOR;
}

private static final Spliterator<Object> EMPTY_SPLITERATOR =
        new EmptySpliterator.OfRef<>();
```

So while they're not reusing an empty stream, they are reusing the empty `Spliterator`, saving a bit in the object allocations.